# How to call data from an API into a spinner?

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit2, android-developer-api

I want to show a district list in a spinner, and i am getting that data through an API.
Here is an example of the response.

```
{
    "districts": [
        {
            "district": "ANANTNAG"
        },
        {
            "district": "BADGAM"
        },
        {
            "district": "BANDIPORA"
        },
        {
            "district": "BARAMULLA"
        },
        {
            "district": "DODA"
        },
        {
            "district": "GANDERBAL"
        },
        {
            "district": "JAMMU"
        },
        {
            "district": "KARGIL"
        },
        {
            "district": "KATHUA"
        },
        {
            "district": "KISHTWAR"
        },
        {
            "district": "KULGAM"
        },
        {
            "district": "KUPWARA"
        },
        {
            "district": "LEH LADAKH"
        },
        {
            "district": "POONCH"
        },
        {
            "district": "PULWAMA"
        },
        {
            "district": "RAJAURI"
        },
        {
            "district": "RAMBAN"
        },
        {
            "district": "REASI"
        },
        {
            "district": "SAMBA"
        },
        {
            "district": "SHOPIAN"
        },
        {
            "district": "SRINAGAR"
        },
        {
            "district": "UDHAMPUR"
        },
        {
            "district": "JAMMU AND KASHMIR"
        }
    ],
    "Request_type": "districts",
    "responseCode": "Success"
}
```

After that, I created 2 schemapojo class for response and dataList as well.

Then, I am calling this into a class but its not working!! I don't have any idea how to call an API and set the response data into a spinner.
Please help

```
private void getdistricts(String state) {

    JSONObject mJobj = new JSONObject();

    try {
        mJobj.put("state", state);
        mJobj.put(REQUEST, "districts");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    Call<districtresponse> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().getDistrict(mJobj);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<districtresponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<districtresponse> call, Response<districtresponse> response) {

            String status = response.body().getResponseCode();

            if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("Success")){
                district_list = response.body().getDistricts();

                districts = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.dist_list,district_list);
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<districtresponse> call, Throwable t) {


        }
    });

}
```

Here in code district_List variable is for a second model class where all district List is available.

I tried a different process from youtube but none of that worked !!

Answer (score 0):

Change code

```
districts = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.dist_list,district_list);
```

To this

```
 ArrayAdapter adapter
        = new ArrayAdapter(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            districts);

    // set simple layout resource file
    // for each item of spinner
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(
        android.R.layout
            .simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // Set the ArrayAdapter (ad) data on the
    // Spinner which binds data to spinner
    spino.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can also try like this**

```
ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = null; //Create A global Variable

Call<Example> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().getDistrict();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {

            if (response.code() == 200) {
                ArrayList<District> districts = (ArrayList<District>) response.body().getDistricts();
                for (int i = 0; i < districts.size(); i++) {
                    stringArrayList.add(districts.get(i).getDistrict());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {


        }
    });

    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.dist_list,district_list,stringArrayList);
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.dist_list,district_list);
    yourSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

And here create a model like this

1. Example Model Class

   ```
   public class Example {

   @SerializedName("districts")
   @Expose
   private List<District> districts = null;
   @SerializedName("Request_type")
   @Expose
   private String requestType;
   @SerializedName("responseCode")
   @Expose
   private String responseCode;

   public List<District> getDistricts() {
       return districts;
   }

   public void setDistricts(List<District> districts) {
       this.districts = districts;
   }

   public String getRequestType() {
       return requestType;
   }

   public void setRequestType(String requestType) {
       this.requestType = requestType;
   }

   public String getResponseCode() {
       return responseCode;
   }

   public void setResponseCode(String responseCode) {
       this.responseCode = responseCode;
   }

    }
   ```
2. District Model Class

   ```
   public class District {

   @SerializedName("district")
   @Expose
   private String district;

   public String getDistrict() {
       return district;
   }

   public void setDistrict(String district) {
       this.district = district;
   }

   }
   ```

I just hope your problem is solved using this